# Insert escaped characters in seq command separator

Tags: command-line, terminal

How do I insert a string containing escaped characters (\n, \t, etc) as separator for the `seq` command?

The standard format includes a newline character:

```
    $ seq 3
    1
    2
    3
```

But if I try to add something plus a newline, the backslash is escaped and a literal "\n" is used instead:

```
    $ seq -s "$\n" 3
    1\n2\n3
```

The same happens using simple quotes, no quotes, or other escaped characters:

```
    $ seq -s "\t" 3
    1\t2\t3

    $ seq -s \t 3
    1t2t3
```

This is not the standard behavior for commands such as `echo`, so I'm a bit confused here...

Edit: Ideally, I'd like a somewhat portable solution (that works in `tsch` as well as `bash`, for instance), and without resorting to Perl or other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, instead of trying to enter the newline character as an escape sequence, simply type it as a newline in the middle of the quoted string by pressing Enter.  For example,

```
bash-4.1$ seq -s "$
> " 3
1$
2$
3
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind, but if someone can supply a more "portable" solution I'd prefer it.

Comment: This is the portable solution.  The problem is that `bash` doesn't process escape sequences in arguments except for the internal `echo` command.  For other commands, the argument is passed straight through to the command, which may or may not support escape sequences. `seq` apparently does not.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. But for me, it works in `bash` but not `tcsh`, so I thought it was the other way around. But I do believe @terdon's solution can be more useful since it allows for instance to use \t in both `bash` and `tsch`, while I cannot type a literal Tab in any of those using gnome-terminal.

Comment: You'll have the same problem in `tcsh`.  It also only processes escapes for `echo`.  You still need the quotes, but to enter a newline is a little different:  You have to type a backslash just before the newline.

Comment: Yes, tab is more difficult in both those shells.  But in `tcsh`, you'll have trouble making @terdon's solution work because `tcsh` command substitution syntax (using backticks rather than `$(...)`) doesn't lend itself to quotes inside quotes, meaning it'll be hard to avoid turning the tab into a space.

Comment: The backslash trick is quite useful, thanks. I did manage to make it work with the newline. Just for the sake of completion, is there any similar trick to input a literal tab?

Comment: In `tcsh` I think the easiest way is to put the tab into a variable, then use it.  `set tab = "\`echo '\t'\`"; foocommand "hello${tab}world"`

Comment: Fwiw, the difficulty you're having here is why, in my own [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) I decided to process escape for **all** commands, not just `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

To get tabs and other strange characters you could also try this:

```
$ seq -s "$(echo -e '\t')" 3
1   2   3
$ seq -s "$(echo -e '\n$')" 3
1
$2
$3
```

Comment: Nice! I can adapt it to `tcsh` as follows: `seq -s "\`echo '\t'\`" 3`. The only problem is the newline doesn't work that way: running `seq -s "\`printf '\n'\`" 3` gives `seq: missing operand` since the newline is processed before the end of the command, I think.

Comment: It's not `printf`, since the same happens with `echo` as well in `tcsh`, when trying to insert a newline. Does it work for you? I'm using gnome-terminal, but since it works in bash I'm not sure the problem is the terminal.
I'm probably accepting your answer, just waiting a little bit in case someone comes with a solution that works in all terminals, for all characters, without Perl or other languages (though I'm not sure such an "ideal" solution exists).

Comment: Too many good answers, it's hard to pick the best one... but I did upvote all those which taught me something, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At least in bash, you can use strings that are interpreted like in ANSI C by using the format `$'string'` (these must be single quotes).

```
seq -s $'$\n' 3
1$
2$
3
```

`tcsh` complains about an illegal variable name, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know -- but as an alternative

```
$ perl -e 'printf "%9d\n",$_ for 6..15'
```

produces

```
        6
        7
        8
        9
       10
       11
       12
       13
       14
       15
```

and

```
$ perl -le 'print "\$$_" for 1..5'
```

produces

```
$1
$2
$3
$4
$5
```

Answer (score 0):

`seq -s "$(echo -e '\n')" 3` doesn't work. A possible solution: `seq -s "$(echo -e '\n\r')" 3 | tr -d '\r'`

Comment: What platform and shell are you using?

Comment: `seq -s "$(echo -e '\n')" 3` prints _"123"_, without _\n_. Reason: The output of `$(echo -e '\n')` is _"\n\n"_; the newline character is in the **IFS** variable, so the shell executes `seq -s "" 3`. Solution: `seq -s $'\n' 3`

Comment: My previous answer is incorrect: the output of the command substitution is literal because the double quotes. True reason: All trailing newlines are removed in command substitution according bash documentation.